# Display days of the week as ticks in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data set that outputs the day of the week (0-6) against a specific number, and I plot the number (y-axis) against the day of the week (x-axis). How can I get d3 to map a 0-6 value to the day of the week (Sunday-Saturday)?

Data (first line):

```
airline,dayoftheweek,cost
Transavia,1,195
```

[image]

I tried

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .ticks(6)
        .tickSubdivide(true)
        .tickSize(6, 3, 0)
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%A"))
        .orient("bottom");
```

but since the first value is 0, it seems to think that it corresponds to 1970-01-01, which is a Thursday, apparently, and doesn't display anything else.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out to be pretty simple:

```
var week = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
```

using tickformat:

```
.tickFormat(function(d, i){
    return week[d]
})
```

Comment: I was thinking that was going to be the case.